# Replacing ceramic tape on Wanhao Duplicator i3

Tags: extruder, monoprice-maker-select, wanhao, duplicator-i3-plus

I need new ceramic tape for my 3D printer. Does it matter which I get? Can I just get the cheapest? Is there a quality difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Wanhao Duplicator i3 too. It does not matter a lot which ceramic wadding and / or kapton  you use. The more you seal off, the better it works. If you have a full metal hotend and a powerful cooling blower and need temps above 250 °C, you might want to do the best you can with a good padding of ceramic and kapton. For normal operation, a half-done job will do just fine.

See this question too: [Efficient and easy way to thermally insulate the heat block of the hotend?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/efficient-and-easy-way-to-thermally-insulate-the-heat-block-of-the-hotend)